# Why don't I have a "Web Service References" menu item in excel/VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, services

I'm trying to consume a SOAP web service from excel. Now according to [This article](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1306) (and confirmed by other articles and MSDN) if I do the following:

- Install the web services toolkit (I've installed v2.01)
- Install SOAP Toolkit 3.0
- Add a reference to Microsoft Soap Type Library (I've tried v3.0 and an older one)

I should get a "Web Service References" menu item in the Tools menu but I don't.

I've also tried adding every reference that seemed to have anything to do with SOAP or XML, but it hasn't helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution since?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but did you try closing excel & reopening to see if it refreshes, hoping everything else is done right ?

from the article:
"Tools → Macro → Visual Basic Editor. On the Tools menu of the VBE, you'll find Web Services References"

Comment: Tried that, but no change. The Tools menu of the VBE has no such item.

Comment: What version of Office r u using ?

Comment: Office 2003

Comment: Ok, try to reboot your machine, see if that helps.